# jQuery media validation by content type

Tags: jquery, validation

I would like to validate **video** files with content type. This is possible for **audios** [Link here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method/). I don't want to validate by mentioning the extensions. But I want to validate whether the file is video file or not?? Is it possible?? or I really need to mention extension for validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_video) all MIME types for videos begin with `video/*`.

So you simply need to change `audio/*` to `video/*`:

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            accept: "video/*"
        }
    }
});
```

Please check working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/k5dBp/).

Answer (score 3):

What about using **HTML5** ? ...

```
<input type="file" name="video" accept="video/*">
<input type="file" name="audio" accept="audio/*">
<input type="file" name="video_audio" accept="video/*, audio/*">
```

*for modern browsers*

**Doc :** [Input#attr-accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-accept)

*so do **fallback** as [@n1ckolas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20265557/622813)*

Answer (score -1):

you only need a file field in your form, the other three default paperclip object properties do not require form fields and are set through metadata tags on the image.

To validate use this in your model:

```
validates :avatar,   :attachment_presence => true,
                     :attachment_content_type => { :content_type => [ 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg' ] }
```

Comment: I asked for videos but u have answered for audio files